# Finding the Jordan basis of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, jordan-normal-form, matrix-decomposition

A linear map $A$ is given in the canonical basis with the matrix $$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2&0&-2&-2\\
1&0&1&1\\
-1&1&-1&-1\\
3&-1&3&3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Determine the Jordan basis $(j)$ and write the map $A$ in it.

What's the general procedure in solving these problems?
I have calculated $A^2$ and $A^3$. $A^3$ is $0$.

If $A^3$ wasn't $0$ I believe I would know how to solve it (the basis then should be $e_1$, $Ae_1$, $A^2e_1$, $A^3e_1$, right?)

But since I can't do that, I don't know what I can do.
I assume the representation in the basis I'm looking for should look like$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @snarski I'm afraid I don't follow. There's a ton of background I'm missing here and my knowledge currently consists of pattern-matching on 2-3 tasks that I have solutions for. Any help?

Comment: If $A^3 = 0$ then all eigenvalues are zero.  Of course I haven't checked that $A^3 = 0$, I'm just taking the OP's word on that.

Comment: there cannot be another eigenvalue different from zero because  the trace(A), sum of the diagonals is zero.

Comment: @abel: I'm not talking about the current matrix because I haven't checked, but $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ has an eigenvalue $0$, trace $0$, and still it has nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: @martin, matrix $A$ in the question has additional information $A^3 = 0$

Comment: @abel: If you know that $A^3=0$ then its eigenvalues are all zero, no need to think about the trace.

Comment: @martin, you are right. $a^3 = 0$ is the crucial one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are jordan chain for the matrix $A$ in your question. let $ej$ stand for the basis vector with all zeros execpt the $j$ the component. chain of length 3 is $e3 \to Ae3 = -2e1 + e2 - e3 + e4 \to A^2 e3 = e3-e4$ and a chain of length 1 is $e1-e3.$ in this basis $\{e3, Ae3, A^2e3,  e1-e3\}$ the jordan form looks like the one at bottom of your question.

Comment: How did you find the $e_1 - e_3$ one?

Comment: @luka, i computed the dimensions $N(A) = 2, N(A^2 = 3$ and $N(A^3) = 4.$ i found $e1-e3, e3-e4 \in N(A)$ and $e2 \in N(A^2).$ now i found $e3$ outside $N(A^2)$ by looking for a linearly independent vector. now, go backwards staring with $e3$ and applying $A$ to reach the chain of length $3.$ the chain of length $1$ is the other eigenvector.